# Creating CRUD with relations to another tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, crud

I have a problem with creating my CRUD controller. I Have Bike model

```
namespace BikeShop2.Models
{
    public class Bike
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string PictURL { get; set; }
        public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
        public Equipment Equipment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My problem is that CRUD does not contains Manufacturer and Equipment even by listing it only. But in another controller it works fine. What may be the problem?
Sample of my controllers. In Details Method required properties are both null.

```
public class StoreController : Controller
{

    BikeShopEntities shopDB = new BikeShopEntities();
    //
    // GET: /Store/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var manufacturers = shopDB.Manufacturers.ToList();
        return View(manufacturers);
    }
    //
    // GET: /Store/Browse?genre=Disco
    public ActionResult Browse(string name)
    {
        var man = shopDB.Manufacturers.Include("Bikes")
            .Single(g => g.Name == name);


        return View(man);
    }
    //
    // GET: /Store/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var bike = shopDB.Bikes.Find(id);
        return View(bike);
    }
}
```

}

This is my SampleData.cs file

```
public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BikeShopEntities>
{
    protected override void Seed(BikeShopEntities context)
    {
        var manufacturers = new List<Manufacturer>
        {
            new Manufacturer { Name = "Orbea" },
            new Manufacturer { Name = "Lapierre" },
            new Manufacturer { Name = "Romet" },
            new Manufacturer { Name = "TREK" },
            new Manufacturer { Name = "Conandale" },
            new Manufacturer { Name = "Specialized" },
            new Manufacturer { Name = "AUTHOR" },
            new Manufacturer { Name = "Cervelo" },
            new Manufacturer { Name = "Kross" },
            new Manufacturer { Name = "FELT" }
        };

        var equipments = new List<Equipment>
        {
            new Equipment { Name = "Shimano" },
            new Equipment { Name = "SRAM" },
            new Equipment { Name = "Campagnolo" },
            new Equipment { Name = "NONAME" },
            new Equipment { Name = "ACCENT" },
            new Equipment { Name = "Easton" },   
        };

        new List<Bike>
        {
            new Bike { Name = "Orca", Manufacturer = manufacturers.Single(g => g.Name         == "Orbea"), Price = 9000.00M, Equipment = equipments.Single(a => a.Name == "Campagnolo"), PictURL = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
            new Bike { Name = "Aqua", Manufacturer = manufacturers.Single(g => g.Name == "Orbea"), Price = 4000.00M, Equipment = equipments.Single(a => a.Name == "Campagnolo"), PictURL = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
        }.ForEach(a => context.Bikes.Add(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: we need more information. are they not showing in the model in other areas?  are they null?  if they are null what is the controller method that populates them?  what have you tried?

Comment: I'm sorry it was my mistake. In the other areas there is no Manufacturer and Equipment too.

Comment: After you run the `Seed()` function, do the rows exists in the database?

Comment: Yes, but I tried to call destroy function on tatabase before initialization.